# Использование переменных в eval

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
            function getResult(result) {
                response = result.langs;
                for (key in response){
                    switch (response[key][0]){
                        case 'A':
                        eval('core_object.language_code.a.'+key+'='+response[key]+';')
                            break;
    //Анологично до конца алфавита
}
```

Значение `response` это объект со множеством значений типа:

```
    {
    af: 'Afrikaans',
    am: 'Amharic'
    //И так далее
    }
```

Значение `key = af` и так далее, а `response[key] = 'Afrikaans'` и так далее.

Тут возникает проблема разобраться в сути которой я не могу: в коде `eval('core_object.language_code.a.'+key+'='+response[key]+';')` переменная `key`, как и предполагалось используется как строка содержащая значение `'af'` а вот строка содержащаяся в `response[key]` используется как переменная из за чего получается ошибка: `ReferenceError: Afrikaans is not defined`.

Почему и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка, которая подается в `eval`:

```
core_object.language_code.a.af = Afrikaans;
```

То, что справа от знака "равно", понимается как переменная. Но такой переменной нет.

```
eval('core_object.language_code.a.'+key+'="'+response[key]+'";')
```

Получится `core_object.language_code.a.af = "Afrikaans";`.

Или

```
eval('core_object.language_code.a.'+key+'=response.'+key+';')
```

Получится `core_object.language_code.a.af = response.af;`.

Или без `eval`:

```
core_object.language_code.a[key] = response[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем там вообще eval? По моему так будет то же самое:

```
case 'A':
  core_object.language_code.a[key] = response[key];
  break;
```